# Finding the duration a note is held MIDI

Tags: java, midi, javasound, duration

I am reading a midi file to figure out the notes and velocity of it, but how would I go about figuring out the duration the note is held?

I know getData1 holds the key, and getData2 holds the velocity, but where would I figure out the duration it's held?

Answer (score 7):

Find out the time for the `note_on` and `note_off` events for a particular note, and calculate the duration by taking the difference.

Comment: +1 Looks like Robert is celebrating the christmas at its best! Merry christmas:)

Answer (score 4):

Robert has already given the theoretical correct answer.
The practical correct answer, as always, is slightly more complex.

Most likely, you won't find many **NoteOff** events, because the end of a note is often encoded as a **NoteOn** event with velocity zero.  This allows to use the **running status** optimization, which avoids to repeat identical status bytes.

The event time is measured in ticks.  In the header of the midi file, you find the **resolution**, which tells you how many ticks are in one quarter note.  The resolution is usually a multiple of 24, to allow using integral tick values for normal, dotted and triplet notes.

This information is sufficient to calculate the note duration **independent** from tempo.

If you need the duration in milliseconds, you need the initial tempo from the header, plus all **tempo change meta events** within the midi file.  Using all tempo changes, you can build a tempo map.  Then you can calculate the time of every tempo change.  Since the tempo is unchanged between two tempo changes, you can calculate the exact begin, end and duration of every note.

Comment: Can someone explain a littler better the meaning of "often encoded as a NoteOn event with velocity zero"? I'm trying to parse notes from a MIDI file using the Java API for it and can't see any NOTE_ON events with velocity equals to 0. Assuming that, how can we really to know the right tick which a note finished playing?